# Constantly prompt user for biometry access

Tags: authentication, flutter, dart, biometrics

I'm using [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) package for user authentication. Is there a way to keep asking the user for permission to use biometric (Face ID/Touch ID) each time that he opens the app even if he denied the access previously? Right now I'm getting `PlatformException(NotAvailable, User has denied the use of biometry for this app., com.apple.LocalAuthentication)`
so maybe there is a way to catch this exception when the app starts and ask the user again to allow access?

```dart
    try {
      bool didAuthenticate = await bioAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason:
            'Please authenticate with biometrics.',
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: true,
      );
      return didAuthenticate;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case 'NotAvailable':
          {
            // prompt the user a massage that asks him to grant access to biometric for this app.
          }
          break;
        default:
          print('e.code = ${e.code}');
      }
      print("ERROR IN BIO AUTH: $e");
      return false;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve here. Why would you want to try to use a feature that the user has denied access to.

Comment: Because, maybe they denied it in the past but after they got tired of entering their password manually each time / suddenly they do trust this app / any other reason that changed their mined...

Comment: Not able to show popup again, instead we can show dialog when user denied and clicked again on biometric button.